# Process of Port 8443 can't be killed

Tags: lubuntu, jboss

I tried to run JBOSS(v5.x)[ubuntu 18.04] and it was saying:

> Deployment "WebServer" is in error due to the following reason(s):
> LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed:
> java.net.BindException: Address already in use /0.0.0.0:8443
> Deployment "jboss.web:service=WebServer" is in error due to the
> following reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on
> 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **

So, tried to kill that process.
To find the PID, used command `lsof -i:8443` and found no process.
Then tried `sudo lsof -i:8443` and got this:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
lxd     11526 root   22u  IPv4 696227      0t0  TCP localhost:8443 (LISTEN)
lxd     11526 root   25u  IPv4 699223      0t0  TCP localhost:41776->localhost:8443 (ESTABLISHED)
lxd     11526 root   26u  IPv4 701114      0t0  TCP localhost:8443->localhost:41776 (ESTABLISHED)
```

Then ran `sudo kill -9 11526` //as without sudo, it was saying operation not permitted.

But again, when I run `sudo lsof -i:8443` I can see new PID(each time I kill it, it runs in another PID!)
I am not sure what is wrong here and what to do.

Comment: `lxd` is a container service - try running `lxc list` to see if you have any containers running that occupy the port.

Comment: ran that command and got this: `| NAME | STATE | IPV4 | IPV6 | TYPE | SNAPSHOTS | LOCATION |`  only column names, not value or items in the table

Comment: Try `lxd shutdown` and see if the ports still are occupied.

Comment: it is gone now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ports have been occupied by the `lxd` container service.

To see your running containers:

```
lxc list
```

If nothing is running, the `lxd daemon` can be closed with:

```
lxd shutdown
```

This should free up the ports.